# A large number of uniquely added UserProperties are assigned to one event

Tags: flurry, flurry-analytics

A large number of uniquely added UserProperties are assigned to one event

Environmental information

OS: iOS

Used LibraryVersion: Ver12.1.1

API used: FlurryUserProperties.set(key, value: value)

Phenomenon explanation
When obtaining event information from RawData, the same content is now duplicated in the userProperties column.
　
Example of UserProperties (If there are many, 100 contents from A to C may be assigned, and there are also cases where only 1 is assigned)

*[AppUserParam{seqId=1, timeOffset=87116, property='A', values=[xxx], userParamCallType=Assign},
　AppUserParam{seqId=2, timeOffset=87116, property='B', values=[xxx], userParamCallType=Assign},
　AppUserParam{seqId=3, timeOffset=87116, property='C', values=[xxx], userParamCallType=Assign},
　
　AppUserParam{seqId=4, timeOffset=792185, property='A', values=[xxx], userParamCallType=Assign},
　AppUserParam{seqId=5, timeOffset=792185, property='B', values=[xxx], userParamCallType=Assign},
　AppUserParam{seqId=6, timeOffset=792185, property='C', values=[xxx], userParamCallType=Assign}]*
→The device with a larger total number of events per day tends to have more duplicate UserProperties.

LibraryVersion: This did not occur when Ver11.3.0.
*Contents A to C were given one each (there were no duplicates)
→Since it is compatible with Xcode14, 11.3.0 can no longer be used.
　
Is there any solution?
Also, if there are any users who have encountered a similar phenomenon, could they please lend their wisdom?
　
Thank you

Is it a problem on Flurry's side?
Also, is it on the app side?
I don't even know the investigation policy.